# Hi, I create a table with only business day, I need to calculate every 4th business day from my date table. Can you please help me?

Tags: sql

My table is like:

```
2021-03-01 
2021-03-02 (for exmp. 3rd March is holiday and not including to table) 
2021-03-04
2021-03-05
... 
2021-05-03
2021-05-04
2021-05-05
2021-05-06
2021-05-07
...
```

And I should get result as 2021-03-05 for march, and 2021-05-06 for may.

So every month I should get the 4th row as date result.

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`.  But the real trick are the date functions.  Let me assume that your database supports `year()` and `month()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(col), month(col) order by col) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks, it's giving me date for only January, how I can run this query to get seqnum every month?

Comment: I am using SSMS 18

Comment: @Juni_sql . . . Nothing in this query is filtering for a single month.  It should be working for all months (that have at least 4 business days).

Comment: @Gordon_Linof True! I made a mistake there, now it's giving all the months as output. How can I modify it for to see just for that month? I will run the query every month and I need 4th business day for the month we are in...

Comment: @Juni_sql . . . Can you ask a new question?  I'm not certain I fully understand your comment.